# Limsup of $\sin(rz)$ as $r\to \infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Prove that for any $z \in \Bbb{C} \backslash \Bbb{R}$

$$\limsup_{r \to\infty}|\sin(rz)| = \infty,$$
where $r \in \Bbb{R}^+$.

---

In the previous part of the question I showed that $$\sin(x+iy)=\sin(x)\cosh(y)+\cos(x)\sinh(y)i.$$
I'm supposed to use this to prove this question, but I'm not really sure how to.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: $z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$ isn't equivalent to $\exists_{y\in\mathbb{R}} z = iy$. For example, you can have $z = 1+i$

Answer (score 1):

We have that $$|\sin(rz)| = \left|\frac{e^{irz}-e^{-{irz}}}{2}\right| \geq \left|\frac{|e^{irz}|-|e^{-irz}|}{2}\right| = \left| \frac{e^{r\text{Re}(z)}-e^{-r\text{Re}(z)}}{2}\right|.$$

One of those converges to infinity and the other to $0$ when $r\to \infty$, the sign of $\text{Re}(z)$ determines which term converges where.

Comment: I just made an edit to my question with your earlier comment.

Answer (score 1):

You have $$\sin(z)=\dfrac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2}$$

Hence  $$\sin(iz)=\dfrac{e^{-z}-e^{z}}{2}=-\sinh(z)$$

Yet you know that :

$$\limsup\limits_{r \to \infty} f(rz)=\infty \Leftrightarrow\exists(r_n)\in\mathbb{(R^+)}^{\mathbb{N}},\lim\limits_{r \to \infty} f(r_nz)=\infty $$

You also know that $$\forall z \in \mathbb{C}-\mathbb{R}, z=x+iy \\ \text{and} \ \sin(rz)=\sin(rx)\cosh(ry)+\cos(rx)\sinh(ry)$$

Take $$r_n=2n\pi/x$$ can you end ?

Comment: Am I correct in thinking then that what I need to show is that as $lim_{r \to \infty}r_n$ that $sin(r_nz)$ goes to infinity?

Comment: It is sufficient indeed.

Comment: What if x = $0$?. Then we'll have $r_n = 2npi/0$

Comment: If x=0 you have to make a distinction case : for example $r_n=2n\pi$ works

Comment: So for $x \ne 0$ I should use $r_n=2npi/x$ and for $x=0$ use $r_n=2npi$? And since $x=0$ it simplifies to $sinh(2piny)$ which is what we needed originally. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes absolutely !